# Can't import data in orientdb

Tags: graph, import, etl, orientdb, nosql

I would like to upload the data in OrientDB, but have errors. 
Here is the json file: Try to upload the data in csv file and make the linkage with server and virtualmachine

```
{
    "source": {
        "file": {
            "path": "/root/Orientdb/bin/temp/datasets/server.csv"
        }
    },
    "extractor": {
        "row": {}
    },
    "transformers": [{
        "csv": {
            "separator": ",",
            "columnsOnFirstLine": false,
            "columns": ["name", "description", "servercategory", "primarysupport", "secondarysupport", "powersource", "serialnumber", "brand", "model", "serverlocation", "osfamily", "osversion", "cpuspeed", "ram", "numberofprocessor", "cpucorecount", "leftpowersource", "rightpowersource"]
        }
    }, {
        "vertex": {
            "class": "Server"
        }
    }, {
        "merge": {
            "joinFieldName": "virtualhost",
            "lookup": "Server.name"
        }
    }, {
        "edge": {
            "class": "VirtualMachine",
            "joinFieldName": "to",
            "lookup": "Server.name",
            "unresolvedLinkAction": "CREATE"
        }
    }],
    "loader": {
        "orientdb": {
            "dbURL": "plocal:/databases/GratefulDeadConcerts",
            "dbType": "graph",
            "wal": false,
            "batchCommit": 1000,
            "tx": true,
            "txUseLog": false,
            "useLightweightEdges": true,
            "classes": [{
                "name": "Server",
                "extends": "V"
            }, {
                "name": "VirtualMachine",
                "extends": "E"
            }],
            "indexes": [{
                "class": "Server",
                "fields": ["id:name"],
                "type": "UNIQUE"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

However, there are errors after run the command (./oetl.sh server.json) . What should I do to fix the issue? Or i should not create the class (Server and VirtualMachine) before run the script? Thanks.

The error message is

```
BEGIN ETL PROCESSOR
[file] INFO Reading from file /root/Orientdb/bin/temp/datasets/server.csv with encoding UTF-8
Started execution with 1 worker threads
ETL process has problem: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OType.NAME
END ETL PROCESSOR
+ extracted 0 rows (0 rows/sec) - 0 rows -> loaded 0 vertices (0 vertices/sec) Total time: 5ms [0 warnings, 0 errors]
```

Comment: Hi, can you post the csv file? Thx

Comment: Thanks Michela, please find the csv file (server.csv) 
 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44206886/server.csv

Comment: Any people can help on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered you on google groups
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/XxdE3UnhFPA

Answer (score 0):

Please use below merge and edge block in your json and check.

{
        "merge": {
            "joinFieldName": "to",
            "lookup":"Server.name"
        }
    }, {
        "edge": {
            "class": "VirtualMachine",
            "joinFieldName":"virtualhost" ,
            "lookup": "Server.name" ,
            "unresolvedLinkAction": "CREATE"
        }

Thanks